# SQL Server: Track new rows across all tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, migration

I am in the middle of collecting data from SQL Server to other locations for processing and storing and I need to find a way to only SELECT new rows since last nightly data collection so I dont need to query 'SELECT *' statements every night.

Any ideas how I could get this done? I don't mind writing some code to get around this.

Something to note:

- I can only access the database and the server by SQL queries
- I can't install any plugins on the database server
- Not all the tables have timestamp or incremental number to refer to

Thank you in advance for all your ideas

Comment: [Track Data Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/track-data-changes-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) will be a good start.

Comment: Assuming you can't implement features such as temporal tables, change tracking, replication or anything else, what is the impact of querying the whole table each night that you're trying to mitigate? Are the tables very large? Do the tables have a rate of data change?

Comment: @HandyD The tables can get to couple million rows. I'm also wondering how much would querying like 10mil rows with SELECT * statement impact the database performance